# About binary classification in Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

When solving a binary classification problem, I think there are two possible ways in caffe.
The first one is using [`"SigmoidCrossEntropyLossLayer"`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1SigmoidCrossEntropyLossLayer.html) with one output unit.
The other one is using [`"SoftmaxWithLossLayer"`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1SoftmaxWithLossLayer.html) with two output units.
My question is what’s the difference between these two approaches?
Which one should I use?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you play a bit with the math, you can "duplicate" the predicted class probability of the `"Sigmoid"` layer to `0.5*x_i` for class 1 and `-0.5*x_i` for class 0, then the `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` layer amounts to `"SigmoindWithCrossEntropy"` on the single output predictions `x_i`.

So I believe it can be said that these two methods can be regarded as equivalent for predicting binary outputs.

Comment: Maybe one should use SigmoindWithCrossEntropy, since this one has fewer parameters at the last layer?

Comment: @whjxnyzh this is an interesting consideration. Personally, I am in favour of SoftmaxWithLoss. Old habits I guess...

Comment: Thanks @Shai. Yes, SoftmaxWithLoss is convenient in caffe, we can get the accuracy using AccuracyLayer.
But we can’t use AccuracyLayer with SigmoidWithCrossEntropy loss since this one only has one output…
Mathematically, these two loss function are the same, in fact SoftmaxWithLoss is overparameterized with doing binary classification. Refer to http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/SoftmaxRegression/ “Relationship to Logistic Regression
” section.